# Copying dimention css styles add spaces, how to fix?

Tags: css, google-developer-tools

A week ago something happened with my dev tools, when I am copying styles like `margin` etc. new line added after each number. For example copying this:

```
margin: 14px 0 3px;
```

...gives me this when I paste it into my text editor:

```
margin: 14
px
 0 3
px
;
```

How to fix it? so the style will be inline

update:
https://prnt.sc/1xd6cfo here you can see i just copy one style in the same dev tool to other elment and there are spaces before 'px'
version of Chrome is 95.0.4638.54

Comment: Add more information, what dev tools? Chrome? Do that happen only copying from it? Have you tried copying code from other places?

Comment: This is likely either a bug in Chrome (i.e. it's copying DevTools styles as HTML instead of plaintext) - or you're abusing Microsoft Word as a HTML editor.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/1xd6cfo here you can see i just copy one style in the same dev tool to other elment and there are spaces before 'px'

Comment: version of Chrome is 95.0.4638.54

Answer (score 0):

it's a devtool bug, chromium team work on it https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1262435